# How to know if user is interacting with app

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiapplication

I need to perform some Heavy UI task.Before starting that task , I want to check if user is interacting with app , like scrolling the table or entering input in textfield. Is there any way to check it ?

Comment: What would you want to do if they are and what if they are not? It may have an impact on solutions/available options.

Comment: I need to insert multiple rows in the tableview. When I do that it block the UI for some time.If user is interacting with the app , I won't insert the row, so that user don't get blocked.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without knowing the specifics -or what your "heavy UI task" is (heavy tasks should be performed in the background in order to *not* block the UI!), but perhaps your best shot is to do what you would do to detect (e.g.) long periods of your app not being used:

Override the method `-sendEvent:` of the `UIApplication` class.

Example:

```
override func sendEvent(event: UIEvent)
{
    super.sendEvent(event)

    // Do your stuff 
    // (e.g., update timestamp of last user interaction)
}
```

Comment: The problem is I need to perform the UI task. So I can't do it on background thread.Thanks for the suggestion. Let me try it.

Comment: I don't remember how to make the app use your `UIApplication` subclass for the application object (instead of the stock `UIApplication` itself), in swift. A web search should give you the answer. Good luck!